# Update multiple - but a subset of - object fields at once without replacing entire document (Spring 3.1 and MongoTemplate for MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, spring-3

I'm trying to update a number of fields at the same time in my "User" document. However, I only want to update some of the fields and not replace the entire document and it's the latter that I cannot seem to avoid. The method I have for doing this looks like so:

```
public void mergeUser(User user) {
    Update mergeUserUpdate = new Update();
    mergeUserUpdate.set("firstName", user.getFirstName());
    mergeUserUpdate.set("lastName", user.getLastName());
    mergeUserUpdate.set("username", user.getUsername());

    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(user.getId())), mergeUserUpdate, User.class);
}
```

My user object does contain other fields - a `password` field being one of them - but if this was set to a value before it is promptly replaced with an empty string or removed entirely. So in the database, this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fc34563c3276c69248271d8"),
  "_class" : "com.test.User",
  "password" : "d26b7f5c0ed888e46889dd1e3d217816d070510596f495e156e9efe4b035fec5a1fe1be643955359",
  "username" : "john@gmail.com",
  "alias" : "john"
}
```

gets replaced by this after I call the `mergeUser` method:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("4fc34563c3276c69248271d8"),
  "_class" : "com.test.User",
  "username" : "john@gmail.com",
  "firstName" : "John",
  "lastName" : "Doe",
  "address" : {
    "addressLine1" : ""
  }
}
```

If I look at the Update object I see it contains the following:

```
{$set={firstName=John, lastName=Doe, username=john@gmail.com}}
```

This looks correct to me and from my understanding of the MongoDB `$set` function, this should only set the values that are specified. I was therefore expecting the password field to remain unchanged and the other fields added or altered accordingly.

As a general discussion point, I'm ultimately trying to achieve some kind of "merge" functionality whereby Spring will auto-magically check which fields are present in the supplied User object and only update the database with the values that are filled in, not all the fields. That should be theoretically possible I would have thought. Anyone know of a nice way to do this?

Here's my user object just in case:

```
/**
 * Represents an application user.
 */
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @NotEmpty( groups={ChangePasswordValidationGroup.class} )
    private String password;

    @Indexed
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    private String username;

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    private Date dob;

    private Gender gender;

    private Address address;

    public enum Gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }

    // /////// GETTERS AND SETTERS ///////////

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return alias;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        this.alias = alias;
    }

    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The code above does work just fine. I made a silly mistake whereby after updating correctly I proceed to save the user object again, which replaces it with a new document.

Comment: Even those this ended up being a non-issue, it helped me.
The documentation shows saving a single field using the $set operator, and excluding the $set operator when saving an entire object; it doesn't mention using $set with an entire object to save parts of the object.

Now I know it is possible to do this. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Having another solution to update an Entity without some fields using Spring MongoTemplate:

```
DBObject userDBObject = (DBObject) mongoTemplate.getConverter().convertToMongoType(user);
//remove unnecessary fields    
userDBObject.removeField("_id");
userDBObject.removeField("password");

//Create setUpdate & query
Update setUpdate = Update.fromDBObject(new BasicDBObject("$set", userDBObject));
mongoTemplate.updateFirst(new Query(Criteria.where("_id").is(user.getId())), setUpdate , User.class);

//Or use native mongo
//mongoTemplate.getDb().getCollection("user").update(new BasicDBObject("_id",user.getId())
        , new BasicDBObject("$set", userDBObject), false, false);
```

Because it uses auto converter so is is very helpful when your entity has many fields.